# Openwhisk - subscribe to queue

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, mqtt, openwhisk

I have oenwhisk system running and working.
I also of RabbitMQ broker that publish messages via MQTT protocol.

what is the best practice to create subscriber for that rabbitMQ and invoke actions in openwhisk?
is it possible by Webhook? Trigger?

- I don't want to create external service that listen and invoke actions, because I'm not get the benefits of openwhisk build in actions and triggers management.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache OpenWhisk does not have a built-in trigger feed for RabbitMQ event source.  It does support Apache Kafka if you can use another general purpose event stream. If this is not possible, there are a few options.

- Use RabbitMQ [Webhook plugin](https://github.com/jbrisbin/rabbitmq-webhooks) to enable RabbitMQ to invoke OpenWhisk actions.
- Use [Alarm feed](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-alarms) to poll RabbitMQ queue on a regular interval for new messages.

Comment: I want to avoid creating service that "always up", because I need to manage it's auto scaling and load balancing.

webhook plugin behind the hood, run service that always up so it's not good for me.
Alarm feed also not solved the issue, because I do need some openwhisk service that always listen.